# why can't I call `ranges::begin` on a `const filter_view`?

Tags: c++, std-ranges

I can't call `ranges::begin` on a `const filter_view`

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view
the `begin` and `end` doesn't seem to be `const`. why is that?

```
int main(){
    std::vector v{1,2,3};
    // removing const will make it compile
    const auto r = v | ranges::views::filter ([](auto&&){return true;}); 
    ranges::begin(r);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/4feaYc

Comment: can't find a dupe right now, but this has been discussed, and it's because the view might have internal state, which can be modified by getting an iterator, etc. basically, you want this thread: https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3/issues/385

Answer (score 4):

All the views in `std::range` library are lazy by design. What it means in practice? It means that under the hood they usually do much more on `begin`, `end` and iterator operations than regular containers. Usually to be able to maintain this laziness some internal state is required. For example filtred view can store iterator to the last matching element or something along these lines. In this case `begin()` changes this internal field. Even the cppreference says this about begin:

> Returns the iterator initialized with {*this, ranges::find_if(base_, std::ref(*pred_))}. In order to provide the amortized constant time complexity required by the range concept, this function caches the result within the filter_view object for use on subsequent calls.

So it makes perfect sense - since there CAN (and most probably is) an internal state which `begin()` and/or `end()` can modify they cannot be made `const`.

Comment: why does boost filtered range work with const?https://godbolt.org/z/Ge1cb8

Comment: @Hui Presumably because it's not lazy by design... or maybe it is but they use `mutable` members, although I have no idea whether that's a design that can work.