# What const views can we not retrieve iterators for?

Tags: c++, constants, std-ranges

This is inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66366084/why-cant-i-call-rangesbegin-on-a-const-filter-view) where the author was unable to call `ranges::begin()` on a const `filter_view`. The answer states that this is because `begin()` may alter the internal state of the `filter_view`.

Are there any other views on which, when declared immutable, we cannot call `begin()`, `end()`, or their read-only counterparts?

Comment: From https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183968/11638718:  `filter_view`, `drop_while_view`, `split_view` and `chunk_by_view` are *never* const-iterable since they do not have a const-qualified `begin()`.

Comment: Thanks @康桓瑋! That's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why must a std::ranges::filter\_view object be non-const for querying its elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67667318/why-must-a-stdrangesfilter-view-object-be-non-const-for-querying-its-element)

Comment: @PolyGlot The accepted answer doesn't, but the second answer does.